# How do I retrieve a value from a [Flag] enum property?

Tags: c#, enums, flags

Say I have an `enum` defined like so:

```
[Flags]
public enum LogLevel
{
    None = 1,
    Pages = 2,
    Methods = 4,
    Exception =8
}
```

and a class like:

```
public static class Log
{
    public static LogLevel Level = LogLevel.Methods | LogLevel.Pages;

    public static void EnterPage([CallerFilePath]string filePath = "")
    {
        if (Level == //What value here to check if Level includes Pages?)
        {
             //Log
        }
    }
```

What value do I need to equate `Level` to to check whether the enum includes `Pages`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, flags must have a `None = 0` value, because otherwise there's no way to represent a `0` mask (i.e. *no value*).

Once you've fixed it, you can check if some enumeration value is in some given flag using [`Enum.HasFlag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag(v=vs.110).aspx) or the bit-wise `&` operator:

```
Level.HasFlag(LogLevel.Pages);
```

...or:

```
(Level & LogLevel.Pages) == LogLevel.Pages
```

Finally, when you implement a flags enumeration, usually enumeration identifier is expressed in plural. In your case, you should refactor `LogLevel` to `LogLevels`.

### Why `&`?

Each enumeration value represents a bit in a complete mask. For example, `None` would be 0, but it could be also represented as `0, 0, 0` where each `0` is one of possible enumeration values in `LogLevels`. When you provide a mask like `LogLevels.Pages | LogLevels.Methods`, then the mask is `1, 1, 0`.

In order to check if `Pages` is within the mask, you use a logical *AND* comparing the mask with one of possible enumeration values:

```
1, 1, 0 (LogLevels.Pages | LogLevels.Methods)
1, 0, 0 AND (LogLevels.Pages)
--------
1, 0, 0
```

- 1 and 1 (true and true == true)
- 1 and 0 (true and false == false)
- 0 and 0 (false and false == false).

The whole *AND* is like isolating the tested enumeration value. If the resulting mask equals the enumeration value, then the mask contains the enumeration value.

### Some OP concern

OP said in some comment:

> Just a quick question on zero value. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8480/2987066) it states that You cannot
>   use the None enumerated constant in a bitwise AND operation to test
>   for a flag because the result is always zero. Does that mean if I have
>   a 0 value I cannot use & and must use HasFlag?

`None` (i.e. `0`) won't be a member of a mask, because 0 *doesn't exist*. When you produce a mask you're using the *OR* `|` logical operator, which is, at the end of the day, an addition.

Think about `1 + 0 == 1`. Would you think checking if `0` is within `1` is ever possible?

Actually, the `None = 0` value is required to be able to represent and empty mask.

Finally, `HasFlag` does the `AND` for you, it's not a magical solution, but a more readable and encapsulated way of performing the so-called `AND`.

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
if (Level.HasFlag(LogLevel.Pages))
{             
   //todo  
}
```